# Does Tor protect me if my threat model includes people around me and behind me looking at the screen?

Tags: threat-models

Can Tor protect me if my threat model includes people around me and behind me looking at the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Tor does not protect you (nor any other software for that matter) if your threat model includes people around you looking at the screen, just as it wont protect you if you have spyware and malware on your computer that captures or logs everything in there.

You can however use the following in combination with Tor to protect you against such threat model:

[image]

Comment: Observers can still see the keyboard, and the user won't even know their keystrokes are being watched!